# React-native-fbsdk issue : AAPT, Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

When I run my app on react-native: I got this message.

```
\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.


:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

this is my Build Gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.elviragraciela.prueban"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'

}
```

And also this is my build Gradle (project)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In addition, there's the Build Gradle (react-native-fbsdk)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+' // support react-native-v0.22-rc+

}
```

I'm running this project on Windows, I've tried several times changing facebook-android-sdk from 4.28 to newer version, but this provocates a failure in com.android.support:appcompat-v7 27.0.2 (it ask for version 27.0.2 which android studio doesn't have it yet

I also have changed compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to a newer version, but this hasn't worked yet.

Comment: did you decrease the sdk version?

Comment: facebook-android-sdk version ?
Yes I did. any version newer than 4.28.0 don't work for me ( because of appcompat-v7 27.0.2

Comment: Try creating a new project with initial SDK version as 26. Downgrading again will leads to same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

first of all AAPT is the Android Asset Packaging Tool, and there are some rules about how to name your assets. For example if I remember well you can't use upper case letter in the name(pictureNew.png use picturenew.png).

Then try to upgrade the sdk, I am using this right now :

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

and:

```
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
 compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4.22.1)"
```

And check if you have included in your path the platform-tools from your android SDK, and the JAVA sdk path.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I changed facebook-android-sdk to [4.22.1), but it didn't work.
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-fbsdk:_debugPublishCopy'.
         > Could not find com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4.22.1).





how can I check the java sdk path ?

Comment: I have react-native-fbsdk v0.70